# How can I combine our bundles with third party libraries into one large bundle for others use?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

There is more than one bundles in our project when we develop RCP product.

We could have one bundle maybe named `common-xxx` that would provide some utils method for other bundle using it.

I want to add some 3rd party jars (such as Apache or log4j etc ) into this `common-xxx` bundle and therefore others should use its API.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

In the `MANIFEST.MF` editor put your jars in the plugin 'Classpath' (on the 'Runtime' tab) - this will add the jars to the manifest `Bundle-ClassPath`.

Then add the packages you want the plugin to export the the `Exported Packages` (also on the 'Runtime' tab). This will add the packages to the `Export-Package` entry in the manifest.

With these two entries the jar packages will be available to other plugins which have your plugin as a dependency.